# Encountered error while building for device

Tags: ios, flutter

The app is running on simulator correctly, but when I try to get the IOS Archive, it's give me a "Build Failled"

> ```
> total size is 55992877  speedup is 1.00
> building file list ... done
> Flutter.framework/
> Flutter.framework/Flutter
> Flutter.framework/Info.plist
> Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
> Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
> Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
>
> sent 426581217 bytes  received 120 bytes  170632534.80 bytes/sec
> total size is 426528750  speedup is 1.00
> /Volumes/Datas/Fasty/flutter_application/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App:
> ```
>
> errSecInternalComponent
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description
> warning: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.akasolutions.fasty" for "Runner" contains entitlements that aren't
> in the entitlements
> file: com.apple.developer.associated-domains.mdm-managed. To use these entitlements, add them to your entitlements file. Otherwise,
> remove unused
> entitlements from your provisioning profile. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
>
> Encountered error while building for device.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLED]

I removed all keys/certs from keychain acces after reinsert it.
It solved my problem.